# Android String Comperision

Tags: android

In my application there is 2 `EditText`s in which if both have same value then shows "Welcome" and if not then shows "You are Unauthorized".

Every time, I get the welcome message only.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btn;
    EditText tx1, tx2;
    String t1,t2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        tx1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        tx2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt2);

        t1 = tx1.getText().toString().trim();
        t2 = tx2.getText().toString().trim();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(t1.equals(t2)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are Unauthorize", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you print those values to logcat using [android.util.Log](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/util/Log.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the getText() methods inside the onCreate, but outside the onClick method. That means the texts will be read as soon as the app starts (i.e. when both edittexts hold empty strings:""), so they will ALWAYS be equal, thus displaying WELCOME.

To prevent this, you want to check the strings when the button is pressed by moving the two 'getText' lines  into the onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    t1 = tx1.getText().toString().trim();
    t2 = tx2.getText().toString().trim();
```

That way, t1 and t2 will hold values of the strings at the moment when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Call `getText` method of `EditText`  inside `onClick` method of `btn` Button to get `EditText` values on Button click:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    t1 = tx1.getText().toString().trim();
    t2 = tx2.getText().toString().trim();
    //.... your code here
}
```